# Cezve doesn't leak with cold water in it, leaks after heating

Tags: turkish-coffee

I have a [cezve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cezve) I bought some time ago. I've tried making some coffee with it, and after about 30 seconds of heating on the stove, it starts to leak (dripping one by one). Is there any way to fix this, or does it have to be thrown away ?

Someone on reddit is suggesting to get some [plumber's solder](http://Get%20some%20plumber's%20solder%20(it's%20lead%20free)%20and%20fix%20it.) to fix it. Is this a good idea ? Any instructions on how to fix this would also be helpful.

Comment: Looks like your second link is mangled; could you fix it? Certainly want to make sure it's lead-free solder (as link text suggests) if you go that route. Sounds like the metal might be expanding when heated and causing a gap. Can you see the leak (hole)? Picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to what @hoc_age said, the metal might be too old and too easy to melt under high heat.

A old and leaking cezve is usually best thrown out to avoid any future leaks and cleanups. Buy a newer version with high heat resistant if the metal is melting too easily. Really it sounds to me that the cevze is a little too old and has been used too much so it is probably best to buy a new cevze in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If Cezve is made of copper, please get rid of it as soon as possible. Copper Oxide is quite poisonous. They are generally plated with tin after production. If you try to fix it, you may break this plating.